# Looping through 2d array in another order

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array consisting of Cells. However, I need to "read" the cells from left to right, like a book. Currently, they are being read from up to down.

Current order:
(X: 3 Y: 0),
(X: 3 Y: 1),
(X: 3 Y: 2),
(X: 4 Y: 0),
(X: 4 Y: 1),
(X: 4 Y: 2),
(X: 5 Y: 0),
(X: 5 Y: 1),
(X: 5 Y: 2),

Wanted order:
(X: 3 Y: 0),
(X: 4 Y: 0),
(X: 5 Y: 0),
(X: 3 Y: 1),
(X: 4 Y: 2),
...and so on

My code:

```
U, L, F, R, B, D = ('U', 'L', 'F', 'R', 'B', 'D')

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row, col, width, total_rows):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.x = row * width
        self.y = col * width
        self.color = WHITE
        self.width = width
        self.total_rows = total_rows
    
    def get_cords(self):
        return self.row, self.col

#CREATES THE GRID
def make_grid(rows, width):
    grid = []
    gap = width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for j in range(rows):
            cell = Cell(i, j, gap, rows)
            grid[i].append(cell)

    return grid

def get_side(cell):
    x, y = cell.get_cords()
    if x >= 3 and x <= 5 and y >= 3 and y <= 5:
        return F
    if x >= 3 and x <= 5 and y >= 0 and y <= 3:
        return U
    if x >= 3 and x <= 5 and y >= 6 and y <= 8:
        return D
    if x >= 0 and x <= 2 and y >= 3 and y <= 5:
        return L
    if x >= 6 and x <= 8 and y >= 3 and y <= 5:
        return R
    if x >= 9 and x <= 11 and y >= 3 and y <= 5:
        return B
    return None

#HERES THE PROBLEM
for row in grid:
    for cell in row:
        if get_side(cell) == U:
            x, y = cell.get_cords()
            print("X: " + str(x) + " Y: " + str(y))
            #print("Color: " + colors[cell.get_color()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If len of rows is the same, it is simple:

```
grid = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
for x in range(3):
    for row in grid:
        print(row[x])
```